# Extract URL from Two Different SiteMaps and Match URLs Without Root Domain In Another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet with two sheets

1. Sitemaps - pull the URLs from two sites
2. Second sheet I need help to extract and URLs from Sitemap1 without root domain in URLMatch Sheet (C Column) and Add URLs in D column from Site2 without root domain but add only exactly matching URLs

Here is the sheet link, and I have no idea how to achieve or do this, kindly help and guide.

Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ii9gzC1p8e_7WFSFtUSftM1iJ11Ep3Ucqvy9KA2E3ws/edit#gid=1115391463

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `regexextract` to get the urls without root domain.

Typically, this in cell `C3` of your URLMatch sheet:

`=arrayformula(if(Sitemaps!B4:B<>"",sort(regexextract(Sitemaps!B4:B,"\.\w+(\/.*)"),1,1),))`

Not sure about what sort of match you want between col C and Col D?

If you want Col D to be the same regex, use this in cell `D3`:

`=arrayformula(if(Sitemaps!D4:D<>"",sort(regexextract(Sitemaps!D4:D,"\.\w+(\/.*)"),1,1),))`

If you want to match values from Col C where they exist in Col D, then delete contents of `B3:B936` and put this in cell `B3`:

`=arrayformula(if(C3:C<>"",if(countif(D:D,C3:C)>=1,true,false),))`

Comment: Hey Aresvik, thanks alot for providing the solution, it definitely works in a way when sorting. i was thinking if there is a way to sort B column exactly as you did with arrayformula and D column pulls only matching entries leave the rest Sitemaps sheet, is that doable?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you need, but if on the 'URLMatch' sheet you only want to display items in Col D where a URL without root domain from Sitemaps!D4:D matches a corresponding value in URLMatch!C3:C, then `URLMatch!D3` would be `=arrayformula(if(countif(regexextract(Sitemaps!D4:D,"\.\w+(\/.*)"),C3)>=1,C3:C,))` If this is not what you need, can show a static example of what you want in `URLMatch!D3:D`?